# Icon size of button in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, icons

How to find the width of the icon which is embedded in a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var icon:DisplayObject = button.getChildByName("upIcon");
trace("icon (width: " + icon.width + ", height: " + icon.height + ")");
```